# How do I close "less" from the outside without it leaving my terminal in a mess?

Tags: linux, less

I'm writing a utility that automatically launches `less` as a subcommand with its output. Some times an error occurs while writing the output, and I would like to automatically close `less` and display the error normally. However, no matter what signal I try to send to the `less` process, it either ignores it or closes "uncleanly", i.e. it leaves my terminal unusable. (However, I can fix the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and writing (blindly) the command `stty sane`.)

I have tried all the "usual" signals: `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGQUIT` and `SIGKILL`. The last one obviously would't work, but I tried it anyway. I can't find anything about signals in the man pages for `less`.

Is it possible to exit `less` cleanly from the outside?

Comment: You can use a fifo as input for less end write a "q" to it, when you want to quit.

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert But I'm already using the stdin of less to feed it text. That said, I'm not sure how less is getting input from my keyboard when its stdin is being used for something else...

Comment: What if you feed it a "q"?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on job control settings, you might be able to first issue a `kill -tstp` to the `less` program, then a `kill -9`. 
The first signal is caught by `less` and makes it restore the tty before re-issuing the signal on itself, which normally makes it pause in the background. However, if the default handler for SIGTSTP is to ignore it, `less` will just continue and set the terminal to raw again.

You might consider running the `less` in a separate terminal, eg `xterm -e sh -c "less /myfile"`, then you can `kill -9` this with no clearup needed.

You can also run `less --quit-on-intr` (or `-K`) and then it will exit cleanly on SIGINT, though this will also affect your normal interaction with the output stream.

Otherwise simply put `stty sane; tput reset` after your kill command.